# Defective matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following linear algebra problem and need help to solve it. I have read the definition of a defective matrix but I still do not have any clue.

For what values of 'x' is the matrix defective?

[1 1 0]
[1 1 0]
[0 0 x]

I will very much appreciate if someone gives enough information to solve it.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: @JORGE, if you are using a square matrix if defective matrix if it is diagonalizable, then your matrix is diagonalizable. this is because spectral decomposition theorem says every symmetric matrix is diagonalizable. in fact $A = S\diag(\lambda_1,\cdots, )S^T$ where the orthogonal matrix $S$ is made up of the eigenvectors of $A.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A [normal matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) is never defective.